How do I find all partial matches, where the search terms are in a two dimensional array, and the lookup table is a single column?
I have a two dimensional array, which is the result of splitting another spilled array by space. Some of the rows in the array have only one value, some have two or three, and so on.
Original spilled array
apple
chocolate milkshake
onion
coffee and chocolate cake

2 dimensional array, which contains the terms I want to search for
apple
chocolate | milkshake
onion
coffee | and | chocolate | cake

The target column:
orangesChocolate
pumpkins
IwantCoffee
appleOnion
coffeeChocolateMilkshake

desired output (with lookup terms next to them)
4       | apple
1;5;5   | chocolate | milkshake
4       | onion
3;1;5;5 | coffee | and | chocolate | cake

Xmatch does not work because it only finds the first match. Filter with isnumber search does not work, I think because search does not know how to handle a 2 dimensional array as input (it returns all false).
How can I have get the result described above?
